# Failed to activate new LV

Tags: lvm

Node1/2 both are in cluster and also in storage group

On Node2 we are assign storage LUN. `pvcreate` and `vgcreate` was successful, but when trying to execute `lvcreate` getting the below error.

```
[root@Node02 }# lvcreate -L +50G -n lv_new_obiee_dev vg_new_obiee_dev
  WARNING: Ignoring duplicate config node: filter (seeking filter)
  Error locking on node Node01: Volume group for uuid not found: 14vT5cBWBm0ic6QhYnBRb3cfjoQeOx9WxInXocuWNrJgiCCPIMcQcpa3Mk6Otsxz
  Failed to activate new LV.
```

Comment: Is `vg_new_obiee_dev` shared between the two nodes? Is it CLVM? or HA-LVM?

Comment: Yes it's clvm the cluster is of 2 nodes

Comment: Can you show the output of pvscan and vgscan on both machines?